# How can I display glyphicon-plus in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm making my blog site via django.
but plus icon is not working in post.html :(
what is wrong?
directory path is blog/templates/base.html, blog/templates post.html

What I've tried to do:
move the <div class "page-header"> to post.html

If you need any information I didn't provide, please ask and I will. Guys, what is wrong? Thanks in advance for any help!

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/style.css' %}">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Django Project</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" ariacontrols="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-lable="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggle-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'home:home' %}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Polls <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'bookmark:list' %}">Bookmark <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}">Blog <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="page-header">
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'blog:post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    {% endif %}
    <h1><a href="{% url 'blog:post_list' %}">Blog</a></h1>
    </div>

   <div class="content container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

post.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="date">
            <p>{{ post.published_date }}</p>
        </div>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using

Comment: I use version3.. isn't it just <rink rel...>?